# Calculate vertices of a bounding box

Tags: c++, geometry, 3d

I am stumped by this problem which looks very simple. I have a 2D bounding box of which I have two corner points. I wish to determine the remaining two corner points. An important constraint: the bounding box can be oriented in any way and not necessarily aligned to the horizontal and vertical axes (i.e. x and y axes).

I wish to do this as I want to raster scan the bounding box.

Comment: They are diagonally opposite, yes.

Comment: If the box is not aligned in space then two diagonal points are simply not enough to determine its geometry. What extra information do you have?

Comment: Two points isn't enough to define the orientation of a rectangle in space. Consider rotating the "correct" rectangle on the axis defined by the line between those two points.

Comment: Note the two points are diagonally opposite. Since I have the diagonal, surely there can only be one box that can be drawn from this.

Comment: In my comment, I gave a way to get multiple boxes given my understanding of the question which is as follows: given the (x,y,z) coordinates of two points, return the unique rectangle (given by the four corner points) for which those two points are opposite corners of the rectangle.

Comment: @dr_rk: no, there is an infinite number of such boxes. Draw a pair of points and try to find 2 boxes that use them: it's not hard. You need another constraint

Comment: Yes you are right in 3D will be infinite such boxes (thru. rotation along the diagonal as you pointed). But what about 2D? In 2D there is only one box, right?

Comment: .. So the other constraint is that we are only working in 2D space.

Comment: A 2d axis aligned box has 4 degrees of freedom: width, height, x pos, y pos. Such a box can be defined with 4 values x1,y1,x2,y2. A non aligned box has one more degree of freedom: rotation. You need more information.

Comment: I ask this question as I need to calculate the smallest 3D bounding box (find all its 6 vertices) of a mesh. Is this impossible? Surely this is easier than finding convex hulls?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'bounding box'? Are you sure that the edges of this box are aligned w.r.t the coordinate system axis? If yes, you could easily calculate the bounding box by finding out X minimum, X maximum, Y miniumum, Y maximum, Z minimum and Z maximum and construct 8 different vertices out of these values (I don't get why you mention about '6' vertices in your question, though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure this is not an answer you want to hear, however, as mentioned here before, two diagonally opposite points are not enough to define a rectangle on a 2D surface.  As a picture is worth a thousand words, here's a picture of two different rectangles sharing the same diagonally opposite points.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't have complete information. Let me explain: Draw a dummy rectangle that you want to find the points for -- make sure the rectangle is rotated i.e. not "flat".

Now, pick the top-left and bottom-right points -- treat them as the top-left and bottom-right points of a rectangle that *is* sitting flat on the x-axis. This shows that you can have at least two rectangles with the same two opposing points. Similarly, you can alter the angle of tilt and get an infinite number of points.

If you want a unique rectangle, you need to define at least the tilt. Hope that helps.

[image: Example figure]

Comment: A bounding box usually refers to a rectangle, therefore you cannot simply skew one rectangle to get another.  I also rather fail to see how your drawing demonstrates the issue.  The two opposing points of the red quadrangle are not the two opposite points of the blue quadrangle.